# Ruby openssl SSLContext cipher

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I wrote following code in Ruby with the OpenSSL library which fetches the certificate chain from cloudflare.com. But Cloudflare has a hybrid system where old browser receive the RSA cert and the new clients receive the ECDSA cert (see https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=cloudflare.com&s=104.17.176.85).
In my case I want to get the older RSA certificate, that is why I set `ctx.ciphers = 'aRSA'`. But somehow I always receive the ECDSA certificate.
Following command works though `openssl s_client -cipher aRSA -connect cloudflare.com:443 -showcerts`.

```
require 'openssl'

ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ctx.ciphers = 'aRSA'
sock = Socket.tcp("https://www.cloudflare.com", 443, connect_timeout: 10)
connection = connect(sock, ctx, hostname)
connection.peer_cert_chain

def connect(sock, ctx, url)
   ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock, ctx)
   ssl.hostname = url
   begin
      ssl.connect_nonblock
   rescue IO::WaitReadable
      return nil unless IO.select([ssl], nil, nil, 10)

      retry
   rescue IO::WaitWritable
      return nil unless IO.select(nil, [ssl], nil, 10)

      retry
   end
   ssl
end
```

Thanks

Ruby Version: 2.6.3
Ruby OpenSSL Version: 2.2.0
OpenSSL Version: LibreSSL 2.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS 1.3 changes how ciphersuites are defind. From the [OpenSSL Wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3):

> The new ciphersuites are defined differently and do not specify the certificate type (e.g. RSA, DSA, ECDSA) or the key exchange mechanism (e.g. DHE or ECHDE). This has implications for ciphersuite configuration.

In your case, even though you are specifying `aRSA`, OpenSSL is still including the 1.3 ciphers, which will work with EC certificates.

I don’t know if it is possible to specify the cipher list to exclude these ciphers (I couldn’t get it to work), but you can simply set the max version to 1.2:

```
ctx.max_version = :TLS1_2
ctx.ciphers = 'aRSA'
```

This should get Cloudflare to use the RSA certificate.

I think the correct way to specify that you don’t want ECDSA certificates in TLS 1.3 is to use the `signature_algorithms` extension field in the request, but Ruby’s OpenSSL bindings don’t support that.